# Change QTableWidget row style on mousehover

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Is there a way to highlight a row of QTableWidget on mousehover?
And if it is QTableView?

I can change a cell color just with foloou stylesheet.

```
QTableWidget::item:hover {
background-color: rgba(200,200,220,255);}
```

What else proprieties QTableWidget has that has hover event?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use delegates to draw the row background

Comment: I have no much experience in Qt and I was looking for the easiest way to do it. If not I will study a little more about delegate. Can you point me any good tutorials? Thank you

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/ I bet this is the best and complete tutorial which you can get online. I have always referred Qt docs for my projects